# get resource names dynamically in c#

Tags: embedded-resource

I want to manipulate all the image files in Drawable..  I've written this code. What's wrong with it?

```
      string[] all = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames();  
        int[] thumbIDs;

        foreach (string resourceName in all )
        {
            int j=1;
            if (resourceName.EndsWith(".jpg"))
            {
              thumbIDs[j]= Resource.Drawable.resourceName;
            }
            j=j+1;
        }
```

Comment: What's not working? Are you getting an error?

Comment: I'm getting this error :  'HelloGridView.Resource.Drawable' does not contain a definition for 'resourceName'